# Nested for loop performance in comparing 2 large data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, nested

I have 2 data frames see 2 examples below . The first is about 3 330 076 lines and the second 400k.

The requirement is fairly simple if the "item code"  in the second dataframe == the article code in the first AND the salesdays entry in dataframe 1 falls between or is equel to "the start" and "end date" entry . Then add a count to the promo count column in dataframe 1 . Below is the nested for loop i attempted but the runtime is more than 2hours without it actually completing . Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
for ind , row in SalesDF.iterrows():
    for j ,row2 in SfPromos.iterrows():
        if (row['article'] == row2['Item Code']) and (row2['Start date'] <= row['SalesDays'] <= row2['End date']):
            row['PromoCount'] += 1
print(SalesDF['PromoCount'] > 0)
```

The requirement is fairly simple if the "item code"  in the second dataframe == the article code in the first AND the salesdays entry in dataframe 1 falls between or is equel to "the start" and "end date" entry . Then add a count to the promo count column in dataframe 1 . I attempted but the runtime is more than 2hours without it actually completing .

Comment: iterating 3Mio * 400k lines takes half a year if every operation takes one microsecond. You need to get off of quadratic scaling if you have data this large. Try to gather stats on ShopritePromos (without even reading SalesDF) than integrating that info back into SalesDF.

Comment: What exactly is in the 'SalesDays'-column? The 's' implies it is a number of days or a range of dates, but you are comparing it to single dates, implying SalesDays is a date.

Comment: SalesDays ==( single date) needs to be in between or equal to Start date and End date

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to have as your output but i think that you may try to experiment with join + group by

Below i am doing left join which is going to combine items with promotions and create some statistics as already mentioned in comment

You can then join them back to original df

```
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sales = [
    (datetime.date(2022, 7, 4), 10123762, 50, 0),
    (datetime.date(2022, 7, 1), 10123762, 50, 0),
]
promos = [
    (10123762, datetime.date(2022, 7, 3), datetime.date(2022, 7, 5)),
    (10123762, datetime.date(2022, 7, 4), datetime.date(2022, 7, 4)),
]

dfSales = spark.createDataFrame(
    sales, schema=["SalesDay", "article", "TotalSales", "PromoCount"]
)
dfPromos = spark.createDataFrame(promos, schema=["Item Code", "Start date", "End date"])

joinedDf = dfSales.join(
    dfPromos,
    (dfSales["article"] == dfPromos["Item Code"])
    & (
        (dfPromos["Start date"] <= dfSales["SalesDay"])
        & (dfSales["SalesDay"] <= dfPromos["End date"])
    ),
    "left",
)

joinedDfWithMatchFlag = joinedDf.filter(joinedDf["Item Code"].isNotNull()).withColumn(
    "Promo Matched",
    F.when(F.col("Item Code").isNotNull(), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
)
statistics = joinedDfWithMatchFlag.groupBy("article", "Item Code").agg(
    F.sum("Promo Matched")
)

statistics.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+---------+------------------+
| article|Item Code|sum(Promo Matched)|
+--------+---------+------------------+
|10123762| 10123762|                 2|
+--------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: this is a very interesting approach , i will check it out . The goal is to count the number of promotions an article/item code  is on per day . The dataframes are different sizes  . the below error got generated    ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects